# How to uninstall an app from iPhone simulator using the command line?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, teamcity

I would like to uninstall or remove an iOS application from the command line. Let's say the application is call ApplicationName, so is there a way to do it from the command line?

Comment: Just remove the app using `rm`. The trick is knowing its path.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From terminal, run:

```
xcrun simctl uninstall booted <app identifier>
```

Comment: This is a great answer, but after quitting my app the simulator shows a black screen. I can re-run the app, but is there any way to instead return the simulator to the iOS springboard after quitting the app?

Comment: shift-cmd-h should get you back to springboard.  SpringBoard should appear automatically after your app quits.  Are you sure you app isn't stuck terminating in the debugger?

Comment: Yeah, the Home button shortcut doesn't work from this black screen either. Stuck there until I re-run the app. The Xcode debugger says `Terminated due to signal 9` and does not seem stuck. [Console logs here](http://pastebin.com/vYHSxybS) if that helps.

Comment: Ah, so uninstalling the app while it's in the foreground is what is the problem.  I suggest that you do `xcrun simctl terminate booted <app identifier>` first to quit your app before you uninstall (or just go back to SpringBoard first).  Note that if you do shift-cmd-h twice (ie "double tapping home"), you'll get app switcher and can get to SpringBoard from there.

Comment: Terminating the app first seems to work half the time, but still getting the black screen regularly as well (if run rapidly together). Regardless, these commands work great as an Automator Service that I can hit from the simulator via a keyboard shortcut. Much faster than Resetting the simulator! Thanks 

Comment: @pkamb Did you find a way to have a dynamic `<app identifier>` or did you hardcoded it ?

Comment: @AnthoPak I believe I hardcoded it for the single app I was mainly working on.